# authblk package and footnote style

Tags: vertical-alignment, authblk

I am happy with the authblk package. However, when there are multiple affiliations (with the footnote style), I would like to be able to add a bit of vertical space between each of them. This does not seem to be possible without tweaking the .sty file?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Title}
\author[1,2]{Author One}
\author[2]{Author Two}

\affil[1]{Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long Name for Department One, Institution One, Address One}
\affil[2]{Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long Name for Department Two, Institution Two, Address Two}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the internal macro `\AB@affilsepx` to add some vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\protect\\\vspace{\baselineskip}\protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother
\title{Title}
\author[1,2]{Author One}
\author[1]{Author Two}

\affil[1]{Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long Name for Department One, Institution One, Address One}
\affil[2]{Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long Name for Department Two, Institution Two, Address Two}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Too bad, I missed that `\AB@affilsepx`. I only decided to unsuccessfully modify `\AB@affilsep`... Thanks!

Comment: The code is not the most transparent. :)

Comment: Clearly:) Even though I am not really able to judge :)